# First page load is really slow - Angular 1.3 + Meteor 1.5.2.2

Tags: angularjs, nginx, meteor

My application is based on angular 1.3 + Meteor 1.5.2.2
And my page loads are slow, especially the first-page load.

How can I optimize these page loads? Is there any tool or something to debug what is taking so much time?
I have been reading articles, some of them were saying that images should not be placed in `myapp/public` folder, I don't understand what is the purpose of `myapp/public` folder then?

I would really appreciate some good performance tips to boost up my application. Thanks

Comment: you can also download extension in chrome with name `Site speed analyzer` this is very good to analyse what takes your website to load so slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Below are my personal experience being with Meteor.

1. It is true that heavy images must not be placed within `public` folder. 
   Meteor serves static assets very poorly. Simple light weight images can be used in `public`, but still I cannot mention what size will not impact performance issues. When you build the project using command `meteor build --server-only .`, if you see the file `program.json` at location `project.tar.gz\bundle\programs\web.browser\`, all the files that are statically served by your server are documented in this file. It gets loaded on runtime and keeps the record of files in memory, so this can also be the reason if you request any data, it may cause little delay in response as it will search through the memory for the image. Once I faced an issue when I loaded huge data of images (around 700MB), though the project build successfully but project never started on hosting server due to more memory requirement. Best way to speed up first page load would be to move those as many of your static assets to `s3` as you can, or at least have something like `Nginx` serve them up instead of Meteor. I also think moving your initial js and css to a CDN could make a big impact. [For more information click me](https://www.yauh.de/do-i-really-need-nginx-with-my-meteornode-js-app/)
2. If the first page has subscription of data, kindly ensure you subscribe very particular data for first page.
3. It also depends how good is your hosting server in terms of configurations that will server your request, I have created many application in Meteor and deployed on various server. Every server has their own serving speed, some give me spectacular response, some do not and in fact all servers are placed in United States.
4. Your network congestion too can cause issues for serving pages. I sometime get quick response but during day time I too get a lag of 2-4 seconds on every request(still this happens rarely.).